smina.exe Entry Point Not Found
I met an error when I tried to use Smina for docking. I installed Smina used order: conda install conda-forge::smina
But it occurs this error when I run Smina:
The Procedure entry point ?sync_flush@zlib@iostreams@boost@@3HB could not be located in the dynamic link library D:/Anaconda3/envs/teachcadd/Library/bin/smina.exe
Could anyone tell me how to solve it? Thanks!
I tried this, but didn't works: How to Fix Entry Point Not Found while installing libraries in conda environment

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
